# spike and slab models

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, generalized-linear-model

Kevin Murphy discusses in this book (http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/index.html) the spike-and-slab model. I am struggling to understand the prior linked to this model. Why, if $\gamma$=0, and we expect w to be zero, is $\delta_0$(w) a reasonable prior? I have trouble making this link, please can someone share their intuition.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence there might not be as clearly expressed as it could be (the use of "expect" in particular could be misleading).

If $\gamma_j=0$ it's telling us that we're in the case where $w_j=0$.

That is expressed by putting all the probability at $0$, and that is just what $\delta_0(w_j)$ says (it's a spike of height $1$ at $w_j=0$).

Comment: Thanks. i did also not realize that the $\delta$ referred to the Dirac Delta. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function